# How to set compare binding in xaml?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to transfer the comparison of attributes in the attribute?
For exmaple:

```
<label isVisible="some>some2">
<label isVisible="1 == 2">
```

e.t.c
like as angular

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `isVisible` is a boolean.

You can Bind this property and do the comparison in your View Model, or in your CodeBehind you can do this.

```
< label x:Name="yourLabel" >

this.yourLabel.isVisible = true ;
```